# Is Paypal developer dashboard down?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to access developer dashboard on https://developer.paypal.com
[image]
At the moment, all the urls are down for me. Shows "This site can’t be reached" on Chrome and "Secure Connection Failed" on Firefox.
I could access them yesterday (28/09), but fail to do so today.
Anyone having the same problem?

Comment: We had this problem for few hours. It is now resolved

Answer (score 0):

Hi something's wrong with servers today, i can't access: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/

```
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Answer (score 0):

Down for me. Can't access dashboard, wanted to do some testing before we go live. Useless.